# How to filter Power BI table using list of keywords (in a column in other table)

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a big data table with a column called Account Name. In another table (*Accounts*) I have a column of Account Keywords that contains parts of full account names. I want to filter the big data by column 'Account Name' using the list of keywords in the 'Acount Keywords' list.

I've created a new measure in the big data table called 'Filter Accounts' with the following DAX:

```
FILTER ACCOUNTS = contains(Accounts,Accounts[Account Keyword],Big_Data[Account Name])
```

But the "contains" function works on exact matches. I want it to return true if the 'Account Keyword' is found within any part of the 'Account Name' field. I also want it to ignore case.

The DAX statement results in TRUE only for exact matches. How do I modify my DAX to achieve the desired non-exact matches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DAX has two functions for text contains matching, `CONTAINSSTRING` and `CONTAINSSTRINGEXACT`, where the latter is case-sensitive but the former is not.

You can find how many keywords match an `Account Name` by writing a calculated column like this on the `Big_Data` table:

```
Keyword Matches =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        Accounts,
        CONTAINSSTRING ( Big_Data[Account Name], Accounts[Account Keyword] )
    )
)
```

To get a `TRUE` or `FALSE` output instead of a count, simply append `> 0` to see if the count is a positive value.

```
Match Exists =
COUNTROWS (
    FILTER (
        Accounts,
        CONTAINSSTRING ( Big_Data[Account Name], Accounts[Account Keyword] )
    )
) > 0
```

Comment: Perfect. It looks like it works. I can now filter the big data table on the new measure. And if I want to add additional filter contraints I can do it within the filter argument!

Comment: Great! If this solves your problem, then please mark the answer as 'Accepted'.