# Wildcard search in the IN operator

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a measure :

Currently I have:

```
a_measure = 
CALCULATE(SUM(table[Count]),
table[status] IN {"Duplicate","Returned - 10+ Days", "Returned - Inappropriate"}
)
```

table is my table

table[Count] is a helper column which has the value "1" for every row. (it's carried over while I work in both Excel and BI - i find it makes summing/counting easier)

What my measure says is:
Sum column Count when the status is Duplicate OR Returned 10+ or Returned - Inappropriate.

What I'd like to do, rather than write out each different type of returned is:
Sum Count When
table[status] = Duplicate
OR
search("return",table[status],0,0)=TRUE

This would be really helpful.
It might be nice to do it as

```
IN {"duplicate",search("Return%"))
```

But I think from the way IN works (https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/from-sql-to-dax-string-comparison/) you can't do that.
If I were doing this in R I could use something like `filter(str_detect(status,"foo"))|status="duplicate"`

If I used countrows, I could filter for each condition but I don't know how to apply the wildcard search in the filter. Can you apply a search in a filter? It feels like you can.

Alternatively, I could write a column in the table so that it assigns it to a group like
Duplicate
Returned  (which has multiple types of Returned)
Closed (which has multiple types of Closed)

and then use table[newfudgecolumn] IN {"Duplicate","Returned"}

Which would technically solve the problem but not in the way that I wanted.

Edit: I need to read this
[DAX Query - Filtering out values from a table in powerbi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63811074/dax-query-filtering-out-values-from-a-table-in-powerbi)

[Search rows with the same ID and apply AND filter to count a particular occurrence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60030722/search-rows-with-the-same-id-and-apply-and-filter-to-count-a-particular-occurren)

Edit :
I've skimmed those and while they work by counting rows that are filtered for each individual condition (which I understand) neither of them applies a search of the field in the individual condition (which is what I want).

tl;dr
I want to apply a wild card search of a field to the IN operator

OR

I want to apply a wild card search of a field in the COUNTROWS operator.

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Related: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56383523), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60660472)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like your R code:

```
a_measure =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( table[Count] ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( table[status] ),
        CONTAINSSTRING ( table[status], "Return" ) || table[status] = "Duplicate"
    )
)
```

You can use `table[status] IN { "Duplicate" }` if you prefer but I can't think of a way to do the wildcard within the `IN` set.

---

Note that the [CONTAINSSTRING function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/containsstring-function-dax) does allow for wildcards `?` and `*`.

Comment: Thank you Alexis. This is exactly the kind of answer I was after for the filter.  In R I might have done something like : list<-c("duplicate","removed","like","this") and then FILTER %IN%list to filter by a variable. Can you do that in DAX?

Comment: I don’t quite follow. Feel free to write a new post for additional questions not answered in this one.

Comment: I think a new question is best! Thanks again