# Power BI: COUNTA across multiple columns with multiple filter criteria

Tags: filter, count, powerbi, calculator, measure

I am fairly new to Power BI and DAX and I am struggling with getting the below measure to work (I have provided to different version of what I have tried). I am trying to COUNTA the # of items that met certain criteria in two separate columns. Each column that the measure looks at has at least 3 filter criteria and in column two I need to use wildcards as the data there in has entries that share the first two values but the 3rd value could change over time. Any assistance would be amazing as I have tried dozens of different ways and I still cannot figure it out.

GA = CALCULATE(COUNTA(Table,[Item]),filter(Table,Table[Column 1]in{"GA","SP"}) , Filter(Table,Table[Column2]in{"MT*","GA*","SP*","OP*"}))

GA = CALCULATE(COUNTA(Table[Item]),Table[Column1]= "GA" || Table[Column1]= "SP" && Table[Column2]="GA*" || Table[Column2]= "OP*" || Table[Column2]]= "SP*" || Table[Column2]= "MT*")

Unfortunately I cannot provide an example of the data.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

As @Alexis Olson mentions in his reply to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65079382/wildcard-search-in-the-in-operator), there does not appear to be a shorthand way to use the `IN` operator with wildcards.

Hence:

```
GA =
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS( 'Table' ),
    FILTER(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Column1]
            IN { "GA", "SP" }
                && (
                    CONTAINSSTRING( 'Table'[Column2], "MT" )
                        || CONTAINSSTRING( 'Table'[Column2], "GA" )
                        || CONTAINSSTRING( 'Table'[Column2], "SP" )
                        || CONTAINSSTRING( 'Table'[Column2], "OP" )
                )
    )
)
```